# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security, spring-ws

I am having an existing SOAP based web-service and I am trying to implement Spring web service security in it using 'XwsSecurityInterceptor' and 'SpringDigestPasswordValidationCallbackHandler'on it. This is how my spring configuration looks like.
[image]

I am deploying this application in JBoss7.1 AS.While the application boots up, following exception is thrown.It complains that the 'com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException' is not found.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping#0':
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/wss/XWSSecurityException
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException

Now I am trying to understand the root cause of that issue. So I am starting with the POM file.

Following dependencies are in pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.ws.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.ws.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.wss</groupId>
    <artifactId>xws-security</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmldsig</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

As a part of my R&D, I went down to the older(2.1.2) versions of 'spring-ws-core' & 'spring-ws-security' along with '1.0.2' version of 'sjsxp'. Application got started and I got an authentication error when i gave an invalid password. Application responds fine if I give the correct credentials. This is what I want to achieve with latest version of these Jars.

Now I want to know why there is a missing with 2.3.0/2.4.0.

So I tried the 'mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose' and found that the 2.1.2 version brings the 'xws-security' along with it.

[image]

So I thought of adding that dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.wss</groupId>
        <artifactId>xws-security</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now that is forcing me to add two more dependencies. I added those too.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmldsig</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But the second one 'xmldsig' is missing in the maven repository. I can download it and manually add it to my local m2 repo. But I would like to fix it in a proper way. 
While searching i came across this thread.
http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/where-to-get-xmldsig-1-0-jar-td92435.html

There someone is talking about an alternative.

[image]

And i could see that this is available inside the 2.3.0 version of 'spring-ws-security:jar'.

[image]

Now my question is, what needs to be avoided/added so that the application boots up with the latest version of jars??   fingers crossed.....

Comment: can you post your pom.xml dependencies (not image)

Comment: added... sometimes i am getting s class not found exception too... thats when i play around with the maven dependencies..

Comment: probably a dependency conflict. check with `mvn tree` ([link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)) or by the WTPlugin for eclipse.

Comment: Those who put a down vote, please give a valid explanation. So that i can add more details and improve the question.

Comment: I do not get what you really want. A lot of information but no clear question.

Comment: @JFMeier. thanks for the comment.I should have thought from someone else's perspective.  I have updated the question and  tried my level best to make others understand the situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes you need to be a software archaeologist in order to debug these things.

Looking at the pom for [spring-ws-security:2.4.0.RELEASE](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/ws/spring-ws-security/2.4.0.RELEASE/spring-ws-security-2.4.0.RELEASE.pom) you can see that the `xws-security:3.0` dependency is optional (amongst others). You would need to read the spring-ws-security documentation to determine which `optional` dependencies that you should include.

Assuming that you have decided that you need the `xws-security` module, you need have a look at [it's pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/wss/xws-security/3.0/xws-security-3.0.pom), which is where the archeology comes into play. This module dates back to 2008, a period when Java 5 was still being supported. Java 6 (and/or Java EE) and newer supports all of the API's in this artifact's dependency list. Including any of them in your build or deployment artefacts is a recipe for pain.

Therefore you should exclude them:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.wss</groupId>
    <artifactId>xws-security</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <!-- Part of JDK -->
            <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <!-- Part of Java EE -->
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <!-- Part of JDK -->
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <!-- Part of JDK -->
            <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <!-- Part of JDK -->
            <groupId>javax.xml.crypto</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmldsig</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <!-- Part of JDK -->
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't get a chance to test it out yet. I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: WOW !!!! Great. Thanks a lot. That worked.  Could you please elaborate your answer? I want to understand it completely.  I didn't understood this portion                                                                                         "This module dates back to 2008, a period when Java 5 was still being supported. Java 6 (and/or Java EE) and newer supports all of the API's in this artifact's dependency list. Including any of them in your build or deployment artefacts is a recipe for pain."

Answer (score 0):

Try with `spring-ws-security:2.4.0.RELEASE` and `spring version 4.3.3.RELEASE`

Comment: Yesterday the title of the question was `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: SpelParserConfiguration.<init>` and the stacktrace for this was `(MSC service thread 1-4) StandardWrapper.Throwable: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParserConfiguration.‌​(Lorg/springframewor‌​k/expression/spel/Sp‌​elCompilerMode;Ljava‌​/lang/ClassLoader;)V at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressio‌​nResolver.(StandardB‌​eanExpressionResolve‌​r.java:98) [spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE].`.

Comment: If the issue is fixed please accept the answer that helped you fixing it and then create a new question for your new issue. If not please update the question with helpful details keeping old title and old stacktrace.

Comment: issue is not fixed. When i created a sample application with selected dependencies, the error is not changing. so i updated the question. Now the error i am getting is consistent.